# Lambda: using .Include() with linked table data in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to filter linked table data using lambda .Include() with the following:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Include(d => d.docs)
           .Where(d => d.docs.startdate >= date1 && d => d.docs.enddate <= date1);
return View(jobs);
```

This doesn't work though.  Does anyone know what the correct syntax is to filter the linked table data correctly?  Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
d.docs.startdate
d.docs.enddate
```

".startdate" and ".enddate" are not showing up in intellisense when I use d.docs.startdate or d.docs.enddate.  I have linked the table relationships and saved the changes but even after using the .Include() command in code, intellisense cannot find the startdate and enddate fields in the docs table through intellisense.

ERROR: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'duedate' and no extension method 'duedate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

...Not sure what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include()` after the `Where()` statement:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Where(d => d.docs.startdate >= date1 && d.docs.enddate <= date1)
             .Include(d => d.docs);
return View(jobs);
```

Comment: Also remove the second d=>    should be d => d.docs.startdate >=date 1 && d.docs.endate

Comment: This keeps failing because ".startdate" and ".enddate" are not showing up in intellisense however the table *IS* linked properly in the database relationships.  How come this field is not popping up in intellisense?

Comment: Try closing the file and visual studio. Then reopening everything.

Comment: Didn't work. I'd like to post my question but I'm not sure if I should do it here.  Should I make a new post and link to that one?

Comment: Yea, I would post a new question because it's a different problem. This answer solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks, post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051148/ef-mvc-how-to-properly-access-linked-table-fields-using-lambda .  As soon as I get this all working I will check this question again too and mark it correct if I can get it to work.  Thanks much!

Answer (score -1):

You should not have two lambdas within the `Where()`. So your query should look like this:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Where(d => d.docs.startdate >= date1)
                  .Where(d => d.docs.enddate <= date1)
                  .Include(d => d.docs);
return View(jobs);
```

or both the Where's in one lambda (what you like more, both has the same result):

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Where(d => d.docs.startdate >= date1 && d.docs.enddate <= date1)
                  .Include(d => d.docs);
return View(jobs);
```

The `Where()` and the `Include()` does not mean the same. `Where()` filters your data, while `Include()` just eager load your data.

Comment: Removing the second d => is correct but you can always use two clauses in the where statement

Comment: Yes you can, but I think it is more readable this way. It doesn't make a different which way you use. Is my answer wrong or why do you downvote it?

Comment: Because it is not true, you are saying the issue is in the pattern, not answering the question

Comment: With saying "not have two lambdas" I meant not having the "d =>" twice. Think that does answering the question. I edited my answer and also posted the second way with having both conditions in one lambda.

Comment: This keeps failing because ".startdate" and ".enddate" is not showing up in intellisense however the table *IS* linked properly in the database relationships.  How come this field is not popping up in intellisense?