# How to properly access linked table fields using lambda?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to access linked table fields using the following lambda code:

```
DateTime dtStartDate = "1/1/2013"; // or some date
var jobs = db.jobs.Include(d => d.docs)
                  .Where(d => d.docs.duedate >= dtStartDate);
```

Here is the table relationship keys in SQL Server:

```
jobs.JobID = docs.JobID
// Note: Check Existing Data = No.
```

So how come the above code does not work when I try to do the following in the first & second lines of code above:

```
 // errors here
 // .duedate can't be found through the .Include() table, docs
 d.docs.duedate
```

The error says:

'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'duedate' and no extension method 'duedate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Class code generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class jobs
{
    public jobs()
    {
        this.docs = new HashSet<docs>();
    }

    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<docs> docs { get; set; }
}

public partial class docs
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> JobID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> duedate { get; set; }

    public virtual jobs jobs { get; set; }
}
```

I have updated the model in Visual Studio to match the DB but still this is not working.  Any idea why? Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need, there are several options:

If you want jobs where *any* of the docs have a due date >= the start date:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Include(j => j.docs)
                  .Where(j => j.docs.Any(d => d.duedate >= dtStartDate));
```

If you want jobs where *all* of the docs have a due date >= the start date:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Include(j => j.docs)
                  .Where(j => j.docs.All(d => d.duedate >= dtStartDate));
```

If you want all jobs and *only* the docs where the due date >= the start date, then it's trickier.  One way is to turn the query upside-down:

```
var docs = db.docs.Include(d => d.job)
                  .Where(d => d.duedate >= dtStartDate)
                  .Select(d => d.job)
                  .Distinct();
```